# How can i calculate the inverse of $\int_{1}^{x} \sinh(u)/u du$?

Tags: integration

I tried it with function composition and differentiate an integral function.

Comment: Well, it's called the hyperbolic sine integral by Wolfram: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SinhIntegral.html